# Phantom AWN Dock that wont go away

Tags: awn

I Have installed 12.04 LTS off the Minimal ISO and installed only the ubuntu-desktop package and ripped out unity and installed AWN. And upon first start i have a phantom dock underneath the actual dock which i cannot get rid of, and i cannot remove it.

I have deleted everything in `~/.awn-settings`, `~/.config/awn` and `~/.gconf/apps/avant-window-manager` and restarted awn and none of the configurations changed.

The docks are still there with the themes i chose  with the applets i chose for the actual correct menu.

I even went so far as i purged all awn packages, did a system wide search for avant and awn and deleted EVERYTHING and reinstalled only to have everything the same.

How can i fix this?

[image: pic]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to post the solution to this. I finally fixed it by deleting the dock on top and  restarting the x server. this made it so i could actually right click the annoying one and delete it as weel. then i readded the one i actually wanted.